# Math: Calculate total IPS in range

Tags: c++, long-integer, largenumber

I'm searching for a way to calculate total number of ips in a range.
For example: between 1.1.1.1 and 5.5.5.5 there are total of 65022 ips.
Right now i have this code:

```
    int Remain = 
    (IP2[0] - IP1[0]) * 256 +
    (IP2[1] - IP1[1]) * 256 +
    (IP2[2] - IP1[2]) * 256 +
    (IP2[3] - IP1[3]) + 1;
```

It works only for low ranges up to c class. For a and b class it gives incorrect results. I think is because number is too large and (int) can't hold it.
Anyone has a correct algorithm to calculate ?

Comment: Remember that `int` is *signed*, and that integer literals (like `256`) are of type `int` unless suffixed with a specifier.

Comment: I really thought Internet is based today in a classless Inter-Domain Routing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, based on what I see, if class C (up to 2^31 combinations) is as far as you can go, it would be a good guess that the signed int is your problem (assuming of course an int is 32 bits on your machine)

However switching to using unsigned ints should sufficiently be able to handle this. However, apparently the different classes have maskings that need to be applied (http://www.vlsm-calc.net/ipclasses.php) so idk if that is supposed to be taken into account.

Also  since all IPv4 IPs are just 4-byte numbers, I offer another quick and dirty way to calculate this, your call to use really, but it would make the masking easier to implement if you need to:

```
unsigned int calculate_available_ips(int r_start[4], int r_end[4])
{
    unsigned int ip1 = r_start[0] << 24 | r_start[1] << 16 | r_start[2] << 8 | r_start[3];
    unsigned int ip2 = r_end[0] << 24 | r_end[1] << 16 | r_end[2] << 8 | r_end[3];

    if (ip1 > ip2) {
      return ip1 - ip2 + 1;
    }
    return ip2 - ip1 + 1;
}
```

naturally masking would then be done by just using bit operation on the uint. As a note, to print out an unsigned value, use `%u` instead of `%d`.

Comment: This works perfectly. I'm going to use this in my future projects!

Comment: should be `%u` to print. changing now to reflect this thanks!